# atof Function not working in program

Tags: c++, string, double, std

In my c++ program I am required to make a class called ComplexNumber that holds information for a complex number. I had written all the functions in the header file and moved the functions over to the .cpp file.

The atof function for my current program is not working. It displays an error stating atof is not in std. When I remove the std:: part of the code the error displays that atof is not declared in the scope.

Here are both example error messages:

> ComplexNumber.cpp:63:33: error: 'atof' was not declared in this scope
>        o.realPart = atof(temp.c_str);
>                                    ^ ComplexNumber.cpp:66:23: error: 'atof' is not a member of 'std'
>        o.imaginaryPart = std::atof(temp.c_str);

The error is coming from my ComplexNumber.cpp file and to be honest I do not know enough about c++ to determine how to fix such a thing. Any help would be appreciated.

---

main.cpp

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: Tyler Weaver
 *
 * Created on February 2, 2015, 4:08 PM
 */

#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

    return 0;
}
```

ComplexNumber.h

```
/* 
 * File:   ComplexNumber.h
 * Author: Tyler Weaver
 *
 * Created on February 2, 2015, 4:10 PM
 */

#ifndef COMPLEXNUMBER_H
#define COMPLEXNUMBER_H

#include <cmath>
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>
#include <string>

class ComplexNumber {
public:
    ComplexNumber(float real = 0, float imaginary = 0);

    ComplexNumber operator+(ComplexNumber o);

    ComplexNumber operator-(ComplexNumber o);

    ComplexNumber operator*(ComplexNumber o);

    ComplexNumber operator/(ComplexNumber o);

    bool operator==(ComplexNumber o);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, ComplexNumber o);

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, ComplexNumber o);

    double getMagnitude();

private:
    float realPart;
    float imaginaryPart;
};

#endif  /* COMPLEXNUMBER_H */
```

ComplexNumber.cpp

```
/* 
 * File:   ComplexNumber.cpp
 * Author: Tyler Weaver
 * 
 * Created on February 2, 2015, 4:10 PM
 */

#include "ComplexNumber.h"

ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(float real, float imaginary) 
{
    realPart = real;
    imaginaryPart = imaginary;
}

ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::operator+(ComplexNumber o) 
{
    return ComplexNumber(realPart + o.realPart,
            imaginaryPart + o.imaginaryPart);
}

ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::operator-(ComplexNumber o) 
{
    return ComplexNumber(realPart - o.realPart,
            imaginaryPart - o.imaginaryPart);
}

ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::operator*(ComplexNumber o) 
{
    return ComplexNumber(realPart * o.realPart -
            imaginaryPart * o.imaginaryPart,
            realPart * o.imaginaryPart + imaginaryPart * o.realPart);
}

ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::operator/(ComplexNumber o) 
{
    double divisor = o.realPart * o.realPart +
            o.imaginaryPart * o.imaginaryPart;

    return ComplexNumber((realPart * o.realPart +
            imaginaryPart * o.imaginaryPart) / divisor,
            (imaginaryPart * o.realPart - realPart * o.imaginaryPart) /
            divisor);
}

bool ComplexNumber::operator==(ComplexNumber o) 
{
    return ((realPart == o.realPart) &&
            (imaginaryPart = o.imaginaryPart));
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, ComplexNumber o) 
{
    out << o.realPart << " + " << o.imaginaryPart << "i\n";
    return out;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, ComplexNumber o) 
{
    std::string temp;

    getline(in, temp, '+');
    o.realPart = std::atof(temp.c_str);

    getline(in, temp, 'i');
    o.imaginaryPart = std::atof(temp.c_str);

    return in;
}

double ComplexNumber::getMagnitude() 
{
    return sqrt(realPart * realPart +
            imaginaryPart * imaginaryPart);
}
```

Comment: Off the top, it's `temp.c_str()`, with a pair of parentheses.

Comment: `atof` need `#include <cstdlib>`.  I do not see you including cstdlib.  *[reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof)*

Comment: `atof()` actually requires to `#include  <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Consider [`std::stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) instead of `std::atof`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to `#include <cstdlib>` in the ComplexNumber.cpp, the `atof` function is declared in that header.

In C++, source files are compiled independently of each other and all functions you want to use should be declared somewhere.  If they are declared in a separate header file, that file should be included before referring to the functions you want to call.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was over thinking and changing so much for just missing an include. I appreciate the fast response.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the appropriate header:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

put this near the top of `ComplexNumber.cpp`

Comment: The OP refers to the function as `std::atof`. For that they need `<cstdlib>`, not `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I missed it while looking for technical things that could have been wrong.